# Brain trainer — exercise perception, cognition and memory

Tags: windows, android, web-apps, educational

There are several apps for perception, cognition and memory training.

Can you recommend one that:

- is based on some scientific background
- has a recognizable / measurable benefit
- doesn't get boring to soon

I'd be happy about a Windows, Android or web application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Luminosity](http://www.lumosity.com) seems to be the largest and extensive brain training web app. part of Luminosity us a project called as [HCP](http://www.lumosity.com/hcp/) that allows people to access their data for various purposes.

[image: Luminosity web app]

The question of whether brain training works or not is [still debated a lot](http://www.sciencebasedmedicine.org/does-brain-training-work/), so it's up to the person really.

Note that Luminosity is subscription based.
[image: Luminosity Subscriptions]